# CAS support for aerospike python client

Tags: python, locking, aerospike

I am using aerospike as the caching layer and need to implement CAS (Compare and Set/Swap). While I am able to find the support for the same with php client (http://www.aerospike.com/docs/client/php/usage/kvs/write.html) the same is not available for python client. Anyone has any idea if CAS is supported for python client as well- and if there's any documentation for the same?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you get a record, the meta data contains the generation:
http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/python/client.html#aerospike-record-tuple

You then need to supply a gen policy to put: http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/python/client.html#write-policies

Then on the put call, you need the meta dict to contain the expected generation. There is an example here: http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/python/client.html#aerospike.Client.put

Comment: Thanks a tonne! Really appreciate the response! Google should really start indexing aerospike pages much more frequently! :)

Comment: Finally got it working using UDFs which handle CAS internally! Thanks!